# a Function returns incorrect value when called from flask app-route

Tags: python, angularjs, python-2.7, flask

I have app route like below

```
import myfile as myfilefunc
@app.route("/data", methods=['GET'])
def data():
        file=request.args.get('file')
        p=myfilefunc.run(file)
        return json.dumps(p)
```

Whenever I run myfilefunc from cmd...It gives me correct results
But when I call it from flask, it usually gives me double the number or totally different number in return.

myfilefunc takes a pcap file as argument, reads it and outputs the data doing series of list operations and gives back a list.

Any idea what is causing such behaviour?
This looks like a concurrent access to same function issue(not sure - I don't have idea about it)

In my application I present list of pcap file for user to select and gives them some data about it once selected.(angularJS makes the call for file using get request)

Can anyone pls help?

Comment: Can you show `myfile` content?

Answer (score 0):

I had a global list in myfilefunc, I just reset it every time function is called to a default value.(it was adding previous values in the newly obtained values)

Works perfectly fine.